# MapReduce task is running but jhist files are not generated

Tags: hadoop, configuration

I'm trying to setup a single cluster master/slave configuration for hadoop-2.7.2. The setup is working and I'm able to run MapReduce test on it. The goal is to run some tests and capture the performance and/or benchmarks.

The problem is, one of the script depends on the jhist file created by the HistoryServer. Although the HistoryServer is running, the jhist files are not created in the `/tmp/hadoop-yarn/`.

The master hadoop and slave hadoop are chrooted and have ssh access to each other. My mapred-site.xml for the relevant part is -

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
    <value>hadoop-master:10020</value>
    <description>Enter your JobHistoryServer hostname.</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>
    <value>hadoop-master:19888</value>
    <description>Enter your JobHistoryServer hostname.</description>
</property>

<property>
        <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.intermediate-done-dir</name>
        <value>/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/history/done_intermediate</value>
</property>

<property>
        <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.done-dir</name>
        <value>/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/history/done</value>
</property>
```

I do not know the inside and outside of hadoop as my goal is to use hadoop to do performance analysis and find bottleneck.